# Appointment system mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query to select all free slots from appointment table but have problem writing such complex query. Maybe someone could help me I will try to explain what I need to get.

I have table structure:

```
    +---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id            | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | patient_id    | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | start_time    | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | end_time      | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The problem is that I need to get free slots. For e.g. The works starts at 8:00 AM and ends at 8:00PM and this goes from Monday to Saturday. From last appointment free space should like 1 year in advance. So here is example response that I expect:

```
    +---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
    | Free Time Start     | Free Time End       | Free Time Length |
    +---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
    | 2014-09-15 08:00:00 | 2014-09-15 08:30:00 | 30               |
    | 2014-09-15 09:30:00 | 2014-09-15 12:00:00 | 150              |
    | 2014-09-15 15:00:00 | 2014-09-15 20:00:00 | 300              |
    | 2014-09-16 09:00:00 | 2014-09-16 11:30:00 | 150              |
    | 2014-09-16 13:00:00 | 2014-09-16 17:00:00 | 240              |
    | 2014-09-16 18:00:00 | 2015-09-16 18:00:00 | 525600           |
    +---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

The sample data for results above:

```
    +----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | id | patient_id | start_time          | end_time            |
    +----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |  1 |          1 | 2014-09-15 08:30:00 | 2014-09-15 09:30:00 |
    |  2 |          1 | 2014-09-15 12:00:00 | 2014-09-15 15:00:00 |
    |  3 |          1 | 2014-09-16 08:00:00 | 2014-09-16 09:00:00 |
    |  4 |          1 | 2014-09-16 11:30:00 | 2014-09-16 13:00:00 |
    |  5 |          1 | 2014-09-16 17:00:00 | 2014-09-16 18:00:00 |
    +----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So in plain query should:

1. Get free space 08:00:00 <= x <= 20:00:00 and through monday to saturday (Other days, hours should be skipped)
2. After last appointment free time range should be 1 year in advance

Sorry if similar questions exists I could not reuse that solutions for hour/day offsets and 1 year in advance... I tried to do this in PHP but it tooks a really long time...

Comment: If you have a presentation layer (e.g. a bit of PHP) then the simplest thing would be to handle the logic of missing results there.

Comment: Yes, I know it would be simple with PHP... But time it takes to calculate everything (around 10,000 rows) is too much...

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. And besides, you'd only ever need to calculate as many rows as could fit on the screen at that moment!?!

Comment: It's a 5 drop boxes Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute it fits all... I need to display 1 year in advance...

Comment: A calendar picker might be more user friendly.

Comment: Yes, but somehow I should remove that hours which are not available

Comment: Yes, so just gather the result into an array and compare the two arrays.

Comment: That you mean get all 10,000 rows and calculate with php?

Comment: Calendars typically display month by month, so you can either get all rows, or all rows for the current month.